Does having a vector containing structs with uninitialized members lead to undefined behavior
If you have a vector containing structs with uninitialized members, is this undefined behavior. The context for this is a vector which is created but then filled in a parallel context, Thus the default initialization of the vector is wasted.
Example
template< typename T >
struct uninitialized
{
    T t;
    uninitialized(){};
    uninitialized & operator=( T const & inT ){ t = inT             ; return *this; }
    uninitialized & operator=( T      && inT ){ t = std::move( inT ); return *this; }
};

std::vector< uninitialized< int > > example()
{
    auto vector = std::vector< uninitialized< int > >(500);

    // Other code unrelated to vector

    for( auto & element : vector ) element = 0; // For loop as stand in for potentially parallel context
    // "0" is simply used as a stand in to keep the example simple

    // Code which might use vector

    return vector;
}

Worth mentioning, the uninitialized members will never be read before they are eventually initialized.
If it matters for the anwser, the intended use is for simple numerical types such as int or aggragate types consisting of those numeric types.
(Also to avoid unnecessary comments, reserve + push_back is not relevant here as the final order of the vector is important)

There is no undefined-behavior (UB) in the posted code:

Creating a vector with 500 elements is OK:
auto vector = std::vector<uninitialized<int>>(500);

All the elements will be constructed with uninitialized's default constructor. The fact that it does not initialize T t is immeterial here.

The loop with assigments is also OK:
for( auto & element : vector ) element = 0;

All the elements will be assigned via uninitialized::operator=(T const & inT ) and their T t will be set to 0.


You can only have UB if you attempt to read an initialized value, but you mentioned that you will not do that, so you should be OK.

Just out of curiosity: what if an element is pushed-back and reallocation is necessary before the vector elements are initialized? Would that be undefined behavior? At this point the existing uninitialized elements would have to be copied to the new place, hence, would have to be read.

@j6t interesting. I think you have a point (but not relevant to the OP's code as posted).

Your given code has no UB as before accessing the data member,  you assign to them in the for loop.
You can simplify your code and make it even more compact by adding a parameterized ctor. This way you won't have to use a for loop at all for assignment and you can just directly initialize vector when defining it as shown below.
template< typename T >
struct uninitialized
{
    T t;
    uninitialized(){};
    uninitialized & operator=( T const & inT ){ t = inT             ; return *this; }
    uninitialized & operator=( T      && inT ){ t = std::move( inT ); return *this; }
    //parameterized ctor added
    uninitialized(T t_): t(t_){} 
};
std::vector< uninitialized< int > > example()
{
    //directly initalized vector 
    std::vector< uninitialized< int > > vectorobj(500, 0); 
  
    //no need for for loop here anymore
    return vectorobj;
}

